# Python - Recursive Date Sorting Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, date

My assignment states that I get a list of birthdays and that I have to arrange them chronologically. I must write my own, so I can't use Python's predefined functions, such this:

```
import datetime
d = ['09-2012', '04-2007', '11-2012', '05-2013', '12-2006', '05-2006', '08-2007']
sorted(d, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%m-%Y'))
```

Here is what I'm thinking of doing.

**Step 1: Red all dates and put them into a list dd/mm/yyyy**

```
date_list = [[1,2,1991],[2,1,1991],[3,4,1992],[5,6,1993],[4,5,1992],[8,5,1993]]
```

For better visualization, I will rearrange them like so:

```
1 / 2 / 1991
2 / 1 / 1991
3 / 4 / 1992
5 / 6 / 1993
4 / 5 / 1992
8 / 5 / 1993
```

**Step 2: Sort the entire list by year (col  2)**

```
1 / 2 / 1991
2 / 1 / 1991
3 / 4 / 1992
4 / 5 / 1992
5 / 6 / 1993
8 / 5 / 1993
```

**Step 3: For each unique year, sort that sublist by the column near it (col 1)**

```
2 / 1 / 1991
1 / 2 / 1991
3 / 4 / 1992
4 / 5 / 1992
8 / 5 / 1993
5 / 6 / 1993
```

**Step 4: Do the same for the sublist of each unique month of that year (col 0)**

```
1 / 1 / 1991
2 / 2 / 1991
3 / 4 / 1992
4 / 5 / 1992
8 / 5 / 1993
5 / 6 / 1993
```

And that should be it. I've used the following functions to try and it:

```
#Sorts the sublist date_list[position..position+length] by the col
def insertion(date_list, position, length, col):
    for i in range (position + 1, pozition + lenght - 1):
        aux = date_list[i]
        j = i - 1

        while j >= 0 and aux[col] < date_list[j][col]:
            date_list[j+1] = date_list[j]
            j -= 1

        date_list[j+1] = aux

    return date_list

def sortDateList(date_list, position, lenght, col):
    # Nothing to do here
    if col < 0:
        return date_list

    # If it's the first sort, sort everything
    if col == 2:
        date_list = insertion(date_list, 0, len(date_list), 2)

    for i in range (position, position + length - 1):
        # Divides the list into sublists based on the column
        if date_list[i][col] == date_list[i][col]:
            length += 1
        else:
        # Sorts the sublist, then sorts it after the previous column in it
            date_list = insertion(date_list, position, length, col)
            date_list = sortDateList(date_list, position, length, col - 1)
            position += length
            length = 1

    date_list = insertion(date_list, position, length, col)

    return date_list
```

I'm not sure exactly what the problem is here, I'm pretty sure it's something really basic that slipped my mind, and I can't keep track of recursion in my brain that well. It gives me some index out of bound errors and such.

For debug, I've printed out info as such:

```
col position position + length
date_list[position:position+length] before insertion()
date_list[position:position+length] after  insertion()
```

Here is what the console gives me:

```
2 0 6
2 0 7
[[1, 2, 1991], [2, 1, 1991], [3, 4, 1992], [4, 5, 1992], [5, 6, 1993], [8, 5, 1993]]
[[1, 2, 1991], [2, 1, 1991], [3, 4, 1992], [4, 5, 1992], [5, 6, 1993], [8, 5, 1993]]
1 0 7
[[1, 2, 1991], [2, 1, 1991], [3, 4, 1992], [4, 5, 1992], [5, 6, 1993], [8, 5, 1993]]
[[2, 1, 1991], [1, 2, 1991], [3, 4, 1992], [4, 5, 1992], [8, 5, 1993], [5, 6, 1993]]
0 0 7
[[2, 1, 1991], [1, 2, 1991], [3, 4, 1992], [4, 5, 1992], [8, 5, 1993], [5, 6, 1993]]
[[1, 2, 1991], [2, 1, 1991], [3, 4, 1992], [4, 5, 1992], [5, 6, 1993], [8, 5, 1993]]
0 7 8
[]
[]
0 8 9
[]
[]
0 9 10
[]
[]
0 10 11
[]
[]
0 11 12
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What Python built in tools are you allowed to use? `datetime` seems forbidden, what about `sorted`?

Comment: It's an assignment for my algorithmic class. It needs to be as handmade as possible. Preferably no built in tools.

Comment: @Jadarma, it has to be recursive?

Comment: Ah, alright. step 1 is definitely a good approach. After that, it would be a single line with `sorted` and a `lambda` expression (or `operator.itemgetter`). Just implement any sorting algorithm (bubblesort for example) and a compare function which compares a list of three elements with another list of three elements, with the last element having the highest priority (the year), the month having the second highest priority, and the day having the lowest priority.

Comment: It doesn't have to be recursive. I just thought it might be simpler and I could extend it if say, it also required to sort the time like ss/mm/hh/dd/MM/yyyy etc

Comment: can you use sorted or do you have to roll your own? Also what is the actual format you get the date in?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I have to make my own. The format is day/month/year and we assume all the dates are valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write a simple sort algorithm and a compare function, such as this:

```
date_list = [[1,2,1991],[2,1,1991],[3,4,1992],[5,6,1993],[4,5,1992],[8,5,1993]]

# first compare years, if equal compare months, if equal compare days
def compare(date1,date2):
    if date1[2] != date2[2]:
        return date1[2]<date2[2]
    if date1[1] != date2[1]:
        return date1[1]<date2[1]
    return date1[0] < date2[0]

for i in range(len(date_list)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(date_list)):
        if not compare(date_list[i],date_list[j]):
            date_list[i],date_list[j] = date_list[j],date_list[i]

print date_list
```

The time complexity is `O(n^2)` but you can improve it by using a more efficient sort algorithm.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it doesn't _have_ to support time, just thought it would be a nice adition.

Comment: If you want it to support time, just extend the `compare` function. It should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert it to `YYYYMMDD` string format you can easily sort it. Try to sort string concatinated data instead of spiting it to 3 part.

Comment: Splitting into a tuple of `(year, month, date)` integers or zero-padded strings would get you the same functionality. You still need to write a sort function though as the OP isn't allowed to use the built-in sort.